# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT and ORDER and merging columns help please

Tags: mysql, csv, group-concat

I've been pulling my hair out for two days trying to put a MySQL query together to pull some data together.  This is beyond my level of experience with SQL, however.

The following query pulls the data that I need, but I need to format it differently so I can use it.

```
SELECT b.key, a.author, a.comment FROM action a, issue b 
WHERE a.issueid=b.id AND a.actiontype='comment';
```

This produces output like so:

```
1 | joe | comment 3
3 | sally | comment 2
1 | sam | comment 2
2 | julie | comment 2
1 | bill | comment 1
3 | joe | comment 1
2 | sam | comment 1
```

b.key is unique and can contain 0-∞ a.comment.  There is a 1-1 relationship with the a.author and a.comment and I must maintain the original association.  The output seems to be in ascending order based on the date of a.comment.

I would like to do get the data into the following format (CSV,) merging the a.author and a.comment results into a single column:

```
"1", "bill - comment 1", "sam - comment 2", "joe - comment 1"
"2", "julie - comment 1", "sam - comment 2"
"3", "joe - comment 1", "sally - comment 2"
```

I played around with several combinations of GROUP_CONCAT and ORDER and also messed with subqueries a bit based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101008/mysql-group-concat-with-an-order-by-count) post and can't seem to get it formatted the way I need. Additionally, it seems like the order of the comment column changes.  I need to maintain the original (oldest to newest) order, but my original query above produces results in newest to oldest order.  If the delimiters pose a problem, I can certainly do some post processing with perl or awk search & replace on the results. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to do it in MySQL?  If not, you might find this much easier with a general-purpose language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT
    issue.key,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(action.author, ' - ', action.comment) ORDER BY action.created ASC SEPARATOR '|')
FROM action
INNER JOIN issue
    ON action.issueid = issue.id
WHERE action.actiontype = 'comment'
GROUP BY issue.key;
```

with some post processing to split based on the pipe character.  If you get truncation issues you may need to increase the value of group_concat_max_len.

Comment: Thanks!  I had to modify things slightly, but this did what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. The join doesn't affect in any way how data is displayed so I'm writing the query as if your table is actually the one you display as the output

```
select concat('"', id, '", ',
  group_concat(concat('"', author, ' - ', comment, '"') separator ", ")
) as result from table1
group by id
```

The ordering of the group_concat is up to you.

Here is an [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/994f9/1).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on adding characters into the results.  '"' didn't work, but I used this concept to insert other characters that I can replace in post processing.

Comment: That's weird, beause the example shows exactly what you're looking for

Comment: I'm running this from mysql -e so it might be something to do with the way the shell interprets the " in the line.  I need to post process the data to strip out line feeds anyway, so I can just replace the characters with "

Comment: Oh, you didn't mention that in the question. Yes, you should probably have to escape the " with \"